# Javascript/HTML HREF created with Variables Doesnt Work with Spaces

Tags: javascript, html, regex, uri, space

I'm using JavaScript in HTML to create an HREF link from a couple of variables. 
The first variable is the fixed text for the start of an Android file path (the same every time) and the second variable is the file name which is taken from an XML attribute. 
It's all works nicely, BUT it only constructs the link properly if I DO NOT have any spaces in the file name variable from the XML document.
Basically what's happening is if the file name variable contains a space, it only constructs the link up until the first space in the file name so an example would be

```
**Correct link =** 
<a href="file:///sdcard/Clients/PB/example file name.pdf">example file name.pdf</a>

**Link my code incorrectly returns =** 
<a href="file:///sdcard/Clients/PB/example">example file name.pdf</a>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
<script>
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("PBFileNames.xml");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file");

var path = "file:///sdcard/Clients/PB/"; //this will be constant between all iterations

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
var filename = x[i].getAttributeNode("name").nodeValue; //the nodefile is the filename
{
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<a href=" + path + filename + ">" + filename + "</a>");
document.write("<br>");
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: Replace the spaces in the filename with `%20` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the URI

```
document.write("<a href=" + path + encodeURI(filename)+ ">" + filename + "</a>");
```

Comment: It's the `filename` part of the uri which has the spaces in it.

Comment: excellent thanks very much raam86, I used the encodeURI() on the filename and it worked perfectly. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers."